Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid account data for instruction
I just follow Mint Token (Lab) course this my code:
import { mintTo } from "@solana/spl-token";
import {
  getExplorerLink,
  getKeypairFromEnvironment,
} from "@solana-developers/helpers";
import { Connection, PublicKey, clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));

// Our token has two decimal places
const MINOR_UNITS_PER_MAJOR_UNITS = Math.pow(10, 2);

const user = getKeypairFromEnvironment("SECRET_KEY_1");

// Substitute in your token mint account from create-token-mint.ts
const tokenMintAccount = new PublicKey(
  "GSb6soUDAfdxuehfgQTmkz98NFudCcgZqWBJnP2rzWbm"
);

// Substitute in your own, or a friend's token account address, based on the previous step.
// const recipientAssociatedTokenAccount = new PublicKey(
//   "RECIPIENT_TOKEN_ACCOUNT",
// );
const recipientAssociatedTokenAccount = user.publicKey;

const transactionSignature = await mintTo(
  connection,
  user,
  tokenMintAccount,
  recipientAssociatedTokenAccount,
  user,
  10 * MINOR_UNITS_PER_MAJOR_UNITS
);

const link = getExplorerLink("transaction", transactionSignature, "devnet");

console.log(`✅ Success! Mint Token Transaction: ${link}`);

Output:
error: Simulation failed. 
Message: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid account data for instruction. 
Logs: 
[
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]",
  "Program log: Instruction: MintTo",
  "Program log: Error: InvalidAccountData",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1162 of 200000 compute units",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: invalid account data for instruction"
]. 


In order to mint tokens, you first need to create the token mint and a token account to receive the tokens. Be sure to go through the whole lesson, since it looks like it explains all of the required steps.
